# Simplify integral with piecewise expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, piecewise

How can I simplify this integral?

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{c[x], 0 <= x <= 1/2}, {0, True}}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I think it should be the same as

```
Integrate[c[x], {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way to just `Simplify` a `Piecewise` integral. But here's something that might achieve what you're looking for (in a hopefully more general setting).

Define a "piecewise integral" function:

```
pIntegrate[p_, {var_, min_, max_}] := 
 Module[{funranges = 
    SortBy[{#[[1]], Sort@Cases[#[[2]], _?NumberQ]} & /@ p[var][[1]], Mean[#[[2]]] &]},

  (* Turn "x < a" into "-Infinity < x < a" *)
  If[Length[funranges[[1, 2]]] == 1, funranges[[1, 2]] = {-Infinity, funranges[[1, 2, 1]]}];
  If[Length[funranges[[-1, 2]]] == 1, funranges[[-1, 2]] = {funranges[[-1, 2, 1]], Infinity}];

  (* Only want the pieces of the function that are defined between the
     limits of integration *)
  funranges = Select[funranges, Or @@ IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{min, max}], #[[2]]] &];
  funranges[[;; , 2]] = Sort[Join[{min, max}, #[[2]]], Less][[{2, 3}]] & /@ funranges;

  (* Integrate the pieces and return their sum *)
  Total[Integrate[#[[1]], Flatten[{var, #[[2]]}]] & /@ funranges] 
 ]
```

Then applying it to your example:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{c[x], 0 <= x <= 1/2}, {0, True}}]

pIntegrate[f, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

But it can also do more complicated things. Suppose `f` has many pieces, which overhang the limits of integration in odd ways (and that the pieces aren't even presented in the right order):

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{a[x], 0 <= x < 1/2}, {c[x], x >= 1}, {b[x], 1/2 <= x < 1}, 
           {d[x], x < 0}, {0, True}}]

pIntegrate[f, {x, -5, 0.75}]
```

[image]

(Sadly, the output is reordered according to Mathematica's whim -- function names? -- and not according to the integration limits of the pieces. But I think there's little that can be done about that.)

I'm sure there must be a cleaner, more concise way of doing this. Also, it would be nice to be able to set the options for `Integrate` through `pIntegrate`. But it works, and perhaps it will inspire someone to do it improve on it.

Comment: You might be interested in ``Internal`FromPiecewise[]``.

Comment: @J.M. Interesting. For functions of one variable it seems to be functionally equivalent to `Reverse@Transpose[f[x][[1]]]` (but includes the default case). I suspect my way would fall apart fairly quickly for two or more variables.

Comment: Pretty much. Using it would definitely simplify your code.